# MockServer monitoring using Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, mockserver, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Is there any solution to monitor MockServer with grafana using HTTP PUT request?
I tried using BlackBox exporter but it doesn't send proper data to grafana.
I need to get only the HTTP status of MockServer (200, 404, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

BlackBox exporter not send data directly to Grafana. BlackBox exporter probing endpoints and represent probe results in metrics endpoints. Metrics must collected from Prometheus. Grafana get data from Prometheus and visualise it.
BlackBox exporter -> Prometheus -> Grafana

Comment: Yes, I connected Prometheus-BlackBox exporter to Prometheus and then to grafana but I can't send the PUT request to the mockserver using BlackBox

Comment: need to see bbe config

Comment: BBE config and logs